# Find out that to which group a number belongs?

Tags: algorithm

I was working on a coding problem and as subpart of it I got this problem:

We are given a number x and we square it so number becomes x^2. Now we have numbers from 1 to x^2 e.g:
if number=4; 
then 
4^2=16

```
         1             ----->1
      2     3          ----->2
   4     5     6       ----->3
7     8     9    10    ----->4
  11    12    13       ----->5
     14    15          ----->6
        16             ----->7
```

Now I am given a number say k and I need to tell that to which group it belongs. Here 8 belongs to 4th group.

What I thought is start from 1 and keep count initialized to 1 and check whether 1<8? if yes then add 2 to 1(prev sum),increase count to 2 and check whether 3<8? if yes then add 3 to 3(prev sum),increase count to 3 and check whether 6<8 if yes then add 4 to 6, increase count to 4 and check whether 10<9? if no then exit. 
So group no. is count i.e 4.

But is there any fast method than my approach?

**EDIT 1:**
I forgot to mention that in my algo when count reaches the given number which is 4 in prev example then I should not add 5 but 3. e.g.:

If number to search is 14 then

```
1<14 yes then add 2

3<14 yes then add 3

6<14 yes then add 4

10<14 yes then add **3**  ---->here I need to add 3 instead of 5

13<14 yes then add **2**  ---->here I need to add 2 instead of 6

15<14 No so output count.
```

it is possible to add 3 instead of 5 using if condition but is there any method in which the value to be added automatically increases and then decreases depending on value of x(see example above to know what x refers to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper half of the rectangle is a triangle:

```
         1             ----->1
      2     3          ----->2
   4     5     6       ----->3
7     8     9    10    ----->4
```

and the numbers on the right side (1, 3, 6, 10) are called [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The inverse formula there (under the subtitle "Triangular roots and tests for triangular numbers") can be used for your problem:

```
def group(x, number):
    if number <= x^2 / 2 :
        return ceiling( (sqrt(8*number+1) - 1) / 2 )
    else:
        return 2*x - group(x, x^2+1-number)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first half, group `i` ends with number `i*(i+1)/2`. So let's assume you are given a number `n` with `n <= x^2/2`, you need to find the smallest `i` with `i*(i+1)/2 <= n`.

Solving `i*i+i-2n = 0` for `i` yields: `((sqrt(1+8n)-1/2)`
E.g. `n = 8`: `i = ceil((sqrt(65)-1)/2) = 4`

Of course, the case `n > x^2/2` is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

First assume for simplicity that **x <= n^2 / 2** and **x** belongs to group **t**. Then:

```
t*(t-1)/2 < x <= t*(t+1)/2
```

From here we get two quadratic inequations:

```
t^2 - t - 2x < 0
t^2 + t - 2x >= 0
```

Here `D=1+8x`, and because t > 0 their common solution will be

```
t ∈ [ (-1-sqrt(D))/2; (1+sqrt(D))/2 )
```

Now remember that t is an integer (and is unique by definition), so we'll get the solution formula:

```
t = floor( 1+sqrt(D))/2 )
```

This was the solution for case **x <= n^2 / 2**. In other case we can solve it by doing:

1. x := n^2 - x + 1
2. find t as described above
3. t := n - t + 1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers on the top-right diagonal are the so-called "triangle numbers", they have formula `n(n+1)/2`.

The numbers on the bottom-right diagonal are equal to 16 minus a triangle number, they have formula `x^2 - (2*x-n-1)(2*x-n)/2`.

So given `k` and `x`, you're looking for the least `n` such that the formula is greater than or equal to `k`, choosing which formula according to whether `k` is greater or less than the `x`th triangle number `x(x+1)/2` (in this case 10). Since both functions are monotonic (always increase) you can do this by solving a quadratic equation for `n` (use the quadratic formula) in floating-point and then rounding up to the next integer (the so-called "ceiling").

To account for floating-point inaccuracies without introducing much complication, you should then check the result using integer arithmetic. It's possible that the floating-point calculation will slightly overshoot or undershoot the correct result, and round to the wrong integer value. For small numbers it won't be out by more than 1 at worst, so the code to detect and correct that is simple, just compare `k` to the value that you get by putting your `n` result into the formula and the values for `n` one either side.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to observe that the `xth` row is exactly the middle row and has x elements in it. So what are the elements in this particular row - they are from `[x(x+1)/2-x, x(x+1)/2]`. So algorithm goes like this:

1. Check if the number to be searched is in the middle row, less than that or greater than that.
2. If in the middle row print x.
3. If less than the middle row, then u need to observe that all rows end in triangular numbers. You can use the formula, `ceil((sqrt(8x+1)-1)/2)` to get the exact row.
4. Else if number is greater than the middle row, then what u can do is think of the lower triangle as this:

   6 5 4

   3 2

   1

That is, all numbers are equal to `x^2+1-that number`. So now you will search for `x^2+1-number to be searched` in the lower triangle with the above formula itself. That gives the row number in inverted form.Let that number turn out to be `k`. Then the value in the correct form is `x-1+k+1`. Finally add `x` to the value to shift the answer to the lower triangle. Hence the answer becomes `2x+k`.

This is an O(1) solution to the problem.